# wget doesn't download images of a website?

Tags: linux, wget, images, download, mirror

I'm trying to download threads of a web forum which contains many images with wget. These images are hosted in a separate domain, so I used the -H flag to allow downloading them. The complete wget order I'm using is:

```
wget -p -H -erobots=off https://example.com/
```

And when I use it almost all downloads except the main images. This is an example of one of those threads I am trying to [download](https://suzuki88.mforos.com/194412/11461305-brico-con-mi-nuevo-suzuki-en-proceso-de-transformacion-muchas-fotos/).

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you getting any error messages?  If you right-click on an image that is not getting downloaded, and either save the URL or open image in a new tab, can you  successfully use wget specifying just the URL of that image?

Comment: I don't get any error messages and if I specify just the URL of the image it downloads correctly.

Comment: @Rick have you finally solved it?

Answer (score 1):

This is a site specific problem. Running

```
 wget -H -p -r --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0" -nd --accept jpg,png https://suzuki88.mforos.com/194412/11461305-brico-con-mi-nuevo-suzuki-en-proceso-de-transformacion-muchas-fotos/
```

gives me a list of robot.txt.* files with content:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow:
```

which basically implies that the website thinks you are a robot trying to patch into some security vulnerability of the site. And the rule is to deny `*` (all) robots access to any part of the site afaiu.

Comment: That robots.txt doesn't deny access, but allows to visit any part of the website AFAIK. [Wikipedia says this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard#Examples): _"This example tells all robots that they can visit all files because the wildcard `*` stands for all robots and the `Disallow` directive has no value, meaning no pages are disallowed: `User-agent: * Disallow:`"_